# Initialize 2d array with variable size

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Using the following method:

```
myArray = [0,1] * NUM_ITEMS
```

Desired result (2d array):

```
[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]...]
```

Actual result (extended 1d array):

```
[0,1,0,1,0,1...]
```

How can I achieve the desired result preferably without using numpy?

Comment: Before someone suggests `[[0, 1]]*NUM_ITEMS`, [no, that doesn't work, even if it looks like it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list comprehension should do the trick:

```
>>> NUM_ITEMS = 5
>>> my_array = [[0, 1] for _ in range(NUM_ITEMS)]
>>> my_array
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged arrays, here's an alternative `numpy` solution using [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> NUM_ITEMS = 10
>>> np.tile([0, 1], (NUM_ITEMS, 1))
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```